# Why does BeautifulSoup reformat my XML?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I do the following:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
html = u'<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.contents
```

As a result I get:

```
[<body><b>In Body</b><b>Second level</b></body>]
```

It looks strange to me since I see not the original XML. Originally I have a tag `<b>` that contains some text (`In Body`) and then it contains another tag `<b>`. However, the `BeautifulSoup` "thinks" that I have tag `<b>` and after it (after it is closed) I have another tag `<b>`. So, the tags are not perceived as nested into each other. Why is that?

**ADDED**

For the people who complain about validity of the HTML in my example I made the following example:

```
xml = u'<aaa><bbb>In Body<bbb>Second level</bbb></bbb></aaa>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
soup.contents
```

which returns:

```
[<aaa><bbb>In Body</bbb><bbb>Second level</bbb></aaa>]
```

**ADDED 2**

If I use:

```
xml = u'<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, ['lxml', 'xml'])
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1147, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1189, in _feed
    SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 138, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 296, in parse_starttag
    self.finish_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 338, in finish_starttag
    self.unknown_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1344, in unknown_starttag
    and (self.parseOnlyThese.text or not self.parseOnlyThese.searchTag(name, attrs)):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: I did not try to create a valid HTML. I wanted to have a valid XML. The tag `<b>` in my example is not supposed to have any meaning (like "bold text" or something else).

Comment: I am using bs4 and did `print soup` and I see that the same HTML is printed as the one I initialized soup with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you're using the obsolete package, [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup):

> This package is OBSOLETE. It has been replaced by the beautifulsoup4
>   package. You should use Beautiful Soup 4 for all new projects

BeautifulSoup 3 contained some XML parsing features (the `BeautifulStoneSoup`) that really did not understand the same tag being nested again (as noted by 7stud in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655491/918959); thus for all XML parsing needs it should be totally and utterly considered replaced by BeautifulSoup 4. Note that these packages can coexist even within an application - `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup` for BS3, and `bs4.BeautifulSoup` for BS4.

---

BeautifulSoup 4 parses using HTML rules by default; you need to tell it explicitly to use XML (requires the `lxml` to be installed). Thus an example with BeautifulSoup 4 (PyPI [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> xml = u'<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
>>> soup.contents
[<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>]
>>> bs4.__version__
'4.1.3'
```

Notice that then the document *must* be well-formed XML; no leniency.

If you do not use the `'xml'` argument, you will get incorrectly parsed documents:

```
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p><p></p></p>')
<html><body><p></p><p></p></body></html>
```

and with

```
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p><p></p></p>', 'xml')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p><p/></p>
```

Comment: It does not work for me. When I try to instantiate the soup object I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'". I put more details into my original question.

Comment: this is possibly from new docs, so you might want to try `'xml'` without a list, or upgrade

Comment: @7stud care to elaborate?

Comment: Whoops...make that three.

Comment: `pip install bs4` does not work for me (`pip install BeautifulSoup` worked out of box)

Comment: it is `beautifulsoup4` in pip (bad package naming)

Comment: When do you plan on actually answering the question: **Why does BeautifulSoup reformat my XML**?

Comment: *BeautifulSoup is a HTML parser by default; you need to tell it explicitly to use XML* it said from the very beginning.

Comment: *You need to tell it explicitly to use XML it said from the very beginning.*--But that's an incorrect answer isn't it?  Here is the error it produces:  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`  But, then you have no idea what the op is talking about, do you?

Comment: I tried to use bs4 and it worked (it did not reformat/changed the structure of my XML). It is important to notice that the version of BS was the crucial. Using the second argument in `BeautifulSoup`, to tell explicitly that I am using XML not HTML did not help in the old version. In the new version, however, it was not necessary to use the second argument (it worked fine without it).

Comment: Notice that it works for this case but you *need* the second argument for parsing `xml`, otherwise beautifulsoup will follow the HTML rules for things like `<script>` and `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

> So, the tags are not perceived as nested into each other. Why is that?

According to the comments in the BeautifulSoup source code:

> Tag nesting rules:
>
> Most tags can't be nested at all. For instance, the occurance of a
>   `<p>` tag should implicitly close the previous `<p>` tag.
>
> ```
> <p>Para1<p>Para2
> should be transformed into:
> <p>Para1</p><p>Para2
> ```

The source code then specifies several lists containing tag names that according to the HTML standard are allowed to nest within themselves--and `<b>` isn't one of them.

> If I use:
>
> ```
> xml = u'<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>'
> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, ['lxml', 'xml'])
> ```
>
> I get:
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
> ```

You are getting that error because you can't pass a list as an argument to BeautifulSoup().

In order to alert BeautifulSoup that you aren't parsing html, you need to use `BeautifulStoneSoup()`.  Unfortunately, my tests show that `BeautifulStoneSoup()` produces the same xml, so it appears that `BeautifulStoneSoup()` applies a similar nesting rule to your `<b>` tag.

If you aren't locked into using `BeautifulSoup 3`, you should use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup 4`.  `lxml` is considered by many to be the superior package (e.g. it's faster, you can use xpaths), but it can be tough to install.   So I suggest you try to install lxml, and if that works, then great.  Otherwise, install BeautifulSoup 4.

I've been using BeautifulSoup for so many years, that I prefer it; but I also use lxml when I want to use xpaths to search a document.

lxml example:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>'
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
print etree.tostring(tree)

matching_tags = tree.xpath('/body/b/b')
inner_b_tag = matching_tags[0]
print inner_b_tag.text

--output:--
<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>
Second level
```

bs4 example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')  #In BeautifulSoup 4, you pass a second argument to BeautifulSoup() to indicate that you are parsing xml.
print(soup)

body = soup.find('body')

inner_b_tag = body.b.b
print(inner_b_tag.string)

--output:--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body><b>In Body<b>Second level</b></b></body>
Second level
```

Comment: @Antti Haapala, Wait is it deprecated or does it not exist?

Comment: Yes, the whole BeautifulSoup 3 is deprecated and BeautifulStoneSoup did exist in BeautifulSoup 4 for some time but it was deprecated and removed, for the very reason that it didn't work.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala,  In your opinion, is bs4 a drop in replacement for BeautifulSoup 3?

Comment: You are right: I did not originally notice he was using BeautifulSoup 3 which is evident from the traceback.

Comment: Also, this is clearly a case of new project or a case of project where beautifulsoup 3 **cannot** work. The deprecation of beautifulsoup 3 was done so that both old and new packages can coexist in an installation. There is no reason for OP to try this *new* parsing task with the old version of beautifulsoup which, as you noted, does not work, or cannot work, because one can use both versions even within the same application.

Comment: *You are right: I did not originally notice he was using BeautifulSoup 3 which is evident from the traceback* -- It was evident from the first line of code.